# Custom Ticks and Labels for Hexbin Colorbar in Pandas/Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

How do I create custom ticks and labels for a Hexbin plot's Colorbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to modifying the colorbar is gaining access to it, then using Locators and Formatters (in [matplotlib.ticker](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html)) to modify them, finally updating the ticks after the changes have been made.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr 

# set the values of the main y axis and colorbar ticks 
ticklocs = tkr.FixedLocator( np.linspace( ymin, ymax, ystep ) )
ticklocs2 = tkr.FixedLocator( np.arange( zmin, zmax, zstep ) )

# set the label format for the main y axis, and colorbar
tickfrmt = tkr.StrMethodFormatter( yaxis_format )
tickfrmt2 = tkr.StrMethodFormatter( zaxis_format )

# must save a reference to the plot in order to retrieve its colorbar
hb = df.plot.hexbin(
    'xaxis', 'yaxis', C = 'zaxis',
    sharex = False
)

# get plot axes, ax[0] is main axes, ax[1] is colorbar
ax = plt.gcf().get_axes() 

# get colorbar
cbar = hb.collections[ 0 ].colorbar

# set main y axis ticks and labels
ax[ 0 ].yaxis.set_major_locator( ticklocs )
ax[ 0 ].yaxis.set_major_formatter( tickfrmt )

# set color bar ticks and labels
cbar.locator = ticklocs2 
cbar.formatter = tickfrmt2
cbar.update_ticks() # update ticks for changes to take place
```

(This issue caused me some significant issues, so I thought I would share how to accomplish this.)